# Redirect request to two Upstream server in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have un upstream list in my Nginx config. And I would to proxy path each request on two servers instead of one.

For example if I have IP1, IP2 and IP3 in my upstream list. I receive a request on /process and I want to redirect this request to two of three servers available in the upstream list (IP1 and IP2 for instance).

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's how i think your config could be, you can create multiple upstreams

```
upstream  main_upstream  {
    server   IP1
    server   IP2
    server   IP3
}
upstream  process_upstream  {
    server   IP2
    server   IP3
}

server {
    location /process {
        proxy_pass  http://process_upstream;
    }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://main_upstream;
}
```

Comment: This will only proxy each request to a single IP in your upstream. The question is basically how to proxy the same request to two servers at the same time instead of one.